# References on Namikawa-Weyl group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, resolution-of-singularities, poisson-geometry

What are the most reasonable references on the definition of the Namikawa-Weyl groups and the first results about them?

In particular, are there more recent (or more educational) texts than the original paper“Poisson deformations of affine symplectic varieties-II" by Namikawa himself?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the beautiful paper ``Springer theory for symplectic Galois groups'' by McGerty and Nevins.
https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.10497

(Symplectic Galois groups is their name for Namikawa Weyl groups.  Maybe it is a better name.)